# how to use down arrow key navigation for textbox and autocomplete using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with text boxes one below the other. I have used jquery to navigate using down arrow.

```
case arrow.down:
//Set focus to the same cell next row
var str = $(this).attr('rel');
str = parseInt(str) +1;
console.log(str);
$("#code_" + str).focus();
break;
```

the navigation works perfect.

Now I have added jquery autocomplete plugin 1.1 to the text box. When I type products in the textbox, the autosuggest box shows products, but I cannot scroll down using down arrow inside the autosuggest box. When I try to scroll with down arrow the focus gets shifted to the next textbox below.

the above jquery script takes priority over the autocomplete plugin. Is there any way when the automplete box is visible the down arrow should navigate within the autosuggest box itself and when the autosuggest box is not visible the down arrow key should navigate to the next textbox below?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete box has [`open`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open) and [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close) events. Use those to control whether your arrow key navigation code should do something (e.g., not when you've seen an `open` but not a `close`).